# ASP classic logic issue

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

I have recently taken over a website written in ASP Classic. It uses a MS access database for the back end.

The website allows people to sign in and pay a membership fee in order to keep there account active.

My Problem is when someones account expires I have no way to change the status of the account from active to inactive. All of the code uses that as a reference rather then the dates. Any suggestions on how I could automatically go through and deactivate accounts as they expire?

Thanks

Comment: Regrettably I do not have access to the server.

Comment: I just checked with the host and that is the only option I can find for editing the database and files.

Comment: I am trying to convince the people that run the website to let me redo it as it was not created by me, and should never have been written this way. I would love to write it with a mysql database. I am trying to do the best I can with what I have been given.... I agree completely about the security issues as this site has tons of holes.. Until I get them to redo the site I am trying to get it as secure and working as effectively as possible.

Comment: The only payment information is paypal, so no payment info is stored. Just the date and amounts. I would never put a credit card info in such a flimsy database...

Comment: Thank you. I will do adjust it like you suggested....

and try and prove to management to redo the site.. the person who wrote it still works there and thinks it's great..

Comment: It seems to me that your question is completely database-agnostic. You could implement exactly the same code against the same schema in a more appropriate database and still have the problem, which is that the code tests a derived flag, instead of the real data (the expiration data). So whether or not to use Jet/ACE as the data store seems completely orthogonal to what I understand to be your actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide details about how you store that information, but perhaps you are able to update account status with an UPDATE query similar to this:

```
UPDATE tblMembership
Set Active = False
WHERE expiration_date < Date();
```

Since you can't connect to the the database directly.  You can run the UPDATE statement from an ASP page.  And open that page when you want to update membership status.

Another possibility is to change the criteria for the query you use to display the membership list.

```
WHERE
    Active = True
    And expiration_date >= Date();
```

That way you would filter out expired members whose [Active] status hasn't been updated yet.

Comment: The website is hosted through namespro. Is there any way to use task scheduler from a hosting company.

Comment: I am fairly new to access, so currently when I download the mdb database it becomes corrupt and unable to open. I would love to do the macro on the database but have no idea where to start on that...

Comment: Would you be able to provide me with some reasons that I can use to convince them to change the website to MYSQL?
-I know that Access database can just be downloaded off the website
-Access databases can corrupt a lot easier
-I am actually able to edit MYSQL online

What else can I use?

Comment: First check which client-server databases the hosting provider offers/allows.  I think security could be the most compelling reason to switch from Access.  Regarding corruption, I don't understand why that's a recurring problem in this case.  It's seldom a problem in a properly designed and deployed traditional Access application.  In the few cases I've encountered where Access was used to feed web pages, corruption was never a problem there, either.  Still, if you're wanting to switch away from Access anyway, you can throw that in as another argument.

Answer (score 0):

There's a number of ways to do this. One thing you can do is create a simple update function that goes through the database, checks dates and "deactivates" any expired accounts. I would put this function into the login proceedure so that it checks the user account and deactivates it if expired. So during login, when the user provides credentials and you take those credentials and compare against stored database values, at the same time you could check expiration dates and deactivate the account if expired. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Hmmm, that would work but part of the website is that members are able "visible" to guests to the website in the search area. So if someone is expired and has not logged in they would still show up.. Plus a lot of members never sign in at all.. Is there any way I could run this script daily or something?

Comment: Yes. You could write a function that is called from a popular page. You could use some logic so that it only executes once a day.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the server, maybe using the task scheduler to run a vb script to update the database as suggested by Damon.